# point QT 5.8.0 to MSVS2017 compilers instead of MSVS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, compiler-errors

I have MSVS2017 installed in my windows 10 operating system alongwith QT 5.8.0. I have just started learning qt. However, the very first program that I built gave following error [image: Screenshot of the error code here] I checked in tools>options>build and run ...but everything I found was concerning 2015 version of visual studio. What I think is because this QT version is referring to MSVS2015 compilers while I have version 2017 installed. Is there any way I can point my QT to MSVS2017 instead of 2015 and compile my project.
My compilers list is as [image]
QT version is[image]
And following options were available in online installer. Ticked are the ones selected by default (the ones I chose). Since 2017 was not present in the list so I chose 2015 version. [image]

Comment: From my understanding, the list of options in the online installer reflect the compilers that that version of Qt was built with (these are usually referred to as "pre-built"). It seems currently the only option to get Qt working with msvc2017 requires you to build Qt yourself.

It seems like Qt 5.9 will support msvc2017, but I'm not sure if that means a pre-built package will be provided.

Comment: seems as if I'll have to wait before I start learning QT..

Comment: If you don't want to have older versions of Visual Studio installed (and I'd recommend getting comfortable with that--although I recently uninstalled Visual Studio 2015 myself), you can always use the MinGW builds of Qt. They work very well. (Don't make excuses for not learning Qt!)

Comment: hahhaha...No excuses at all.. I'll straightforward go to MinGW..Just one thing, if an update to QT is released that supports MSVS 2017, Will it be possible to use that compiler (MSVS) for my previous compiled projects? I mean if there is any change of syntax during coding for either compiler

Comment: Nope, there shouldn't be. Right now it looks like 5.9 will support vs2017, although it's unclear if that means that it will compile with vs2017 or if they will provide prebuilt packages for vs2017. Once that happens you'll have to update (through the maintenance tool), and then set up new "kits" for your project to compile with msvc.